# Designing Testing Framework in Python!

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to design a framework in Python for testing Development Codes..

For e.g.

I wrote a small program in python only to add to numbers. And now I would like to test this Python code in an automated way by storing the Inputs and expected Output at some place and now I just run the python script to validate the Output.

Can You please help me starting this? Any Good Documentation on testing will be good!!

And Experienced people please share Scope of Python Programming, where it could be used, etc.

Thanks :)

Comment: [Already in the standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html) in [more than one implementation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html)

Comment: If you want to implement your own testing framework as a learning exercise, then you will have to put some work into it and come back with a specific question. If you don't have a specific question, then you might benefit from first gaining experience in using one or more of the frameworks mentioned here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were thinking of writing your own unit testing library from scratch, that is rather unncessary. There are already many to choose from, including one in the standard library! ([unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html))

[Nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/1.0.0/) is a popular alternative to using the standard library's unittest.

Here's a good tutorial on using it: http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/nose-intro.html